# I couldn't put my mobile menu on front of my slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, express, ejs

I made a slider for hero component and mobile menu for header component. But i couldn't put the mobile menu in front of slider.

I tried to give negative z-index to the slider pictures but when i do that slider won't work, so i can't make that.

here is placement of the components on the pages:

```
<body>
    <%- include("../components/top-bar.ejs") %>
    <%- include("../components/header.ejs") %> // mobile navbar placed on here
    <%- include("../components/navbar.ejs") %>
    <%- include("../components/hero.ejs") %> // slider placed on here
```

header.ejs:

```
<section class="header-container">
    <div class="header-flex">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/"><img src="laraside-logo.png" alt="Laraside Emlak Logosu"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="searchbar">
            <form action="/search" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="adtitle" id="" placeholder="İlan Başlığı İle Ara...">
                <button><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="color: gray;"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="telephone">
            <div class="instagram-image-container">
                <a href="#" class="instagram-image" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #833ab4, #fd1d1d, #fcb045);"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram" style="color: #f7f7f7;"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="telephone-grid">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-phone" style="color: #59AEE9;"></i>
                <span style="grid-row: 1;">Bize Ulaşın:</span>
                <span style="grid-row: 2;">0 324 000 00 00</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="mobile-menu">
            <button class="mobile-menu-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #000000; font-size: 30px;"></i></button>

            <div class="mobile-menu-list">
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-home" style="--fa-primary-color: #ffffff; --fa-secondary-color: #ffffff;"></i> Anasayfa</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/hakkimizda">Hakkımızda</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/misyonumuz">Misyonumuz</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/vizyonumuz">Vizyonumuz</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/satilik-ilanlari">Satılık</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/kiralik-ilanlari">Kiralık</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="#">Şubelerimiz</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/danismanlarimiz">Danışmanlar</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/haberler">Haberler</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/musteri-yorumlari">Müşteri Yorumları</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/iletisim">İletişim</a>
                <a class="mobile-menu-buttons" href="/talep-sayfasi"><span>Talep Gönder</span></a>

            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>
</section>

<div class="dp-flex-when-650px">
    <div class="mobile-searchbar">
        <form action="/search" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="adtitle" id="" placeholder="İlan Başlığı İle Ara...">
            <button><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="color: gray;"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .header-container{
        translate: 0 1.6em;
    }

    .header-flex{
        margin: 0 10vw;
        display: flex;
        place-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .header-flex > *{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .logo{

    }

    .logo img{
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 100px;
    }

    .searchbar{
        width: 22em;
    }

    .searchbar form{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border-color: gray;
    }

    .searchbar form > *{
        border-color: gray !important;
    }

    .searchbar form input{
        padding: 0.75em 0;
        width: 22em;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-right: none;
    }

    .searchbar form button{
        padding: 0.75em 0;
        width: 3em;
        border-width: 1px;
        background-color: white;
        border-left: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .telephone{
        display: flex;
        place-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 15px;
        width: 18vw;
    }

    .telephone-grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
        gap: 3px;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .telephone-grid i{
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1 / span 2;
        font-size: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .telephone-grid span:first-of-type{
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        width: 10vw;
        translate: 0 0.9em;
    }

    .telephone-grid span:last-of-type{
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        width: 10vw;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .instagram-image-container{
        display: flex;
        place-content: center;
    }

    .instagram-image{
        width: 36px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .instagram-image i{
        text-align: center;
        width: 35px;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .instagram-image:hover{
        opacity: 70%;
    }

    .mobile-menu{
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1000000;
    }

    .mobile-menu-button{
        background-color: #ebf1f5;
        border: none;
    }

    .mobile-menu-list{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 1em;
        background-color: black;
        translate: -50px;
        z-index: 1000000;
    }

    .mobile-menu-list a{
        z-index: 1000000000;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }

    .open-mobile-menu-list{
        display: block !important;
    }

    .dp-flex-when-650px{
        display: none;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .mobile-searchbar{
        width: 22em;
    }

    .mobile-searchbar form{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border-color: gray;
    }

    .mobile-searchbar form > *{
        border-color: gray !important;
    }

    .mobile-searchbar form input{
        padding: 0.75em 0;
        width: 22em;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-right: none;
    }

    .mobile-searchbar form button{
        padding: 0.75em 0;
        width: 3em;
        border-width: 1px;
        background-color: white;
        border-left: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
        .logo img{
            width: 120px;
            height: 80px;
        }

        .searchbar form{
            translate: 5em;
        }

        .searchbar form input{
            width: 15em;
        }

        .telephone-grid span:first-of-type{
            font-size: 0.6rem;
            width: 12vw;
            translate: 0 0.9em;
        }

        .telephone-grid span:last-of-type{
            display: block;
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            width: 12vw;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
        .telephone{
            display: none;
        }

        .mobile-menu{
            display: block;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 650px){
        .searchbar{
            display: none;
        }

        .dp-flex-when-650px{
            display: flex;
        }
    }
</style>

<script>
    let mobileMenuButton = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu-button");
    let mobileMenuList = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu-list");

    mobileMenuButton.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(){
        mobileMenuList.classList.toggle("open-mobile-menu-list");
    })
</script>
```

hero.ejs:

```
<div class="hero-container">
    <div class="new-hero-prev-slide"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
    <section class="hero">
        <img src="hero-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="he-first he-active">
        <img src="hero-placeholder 2.jpg" draggable="false" alt="">
        <img src="hero-placeholder 3.jpg" draggable="false" alt="">
        <img src="hero-placeholder 4.jpg" draggable="false" alt=""> 
        <img src="hero-placeholder 4.jpg" draggable="false" alt="" class="he-last">
    </section>
    <div class="new-hero-next-slide"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
</div>

<style>
    .hero-container{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 10;
        /* Akla hayale gelmeyecek bir saçmalık, chatgpt bile bunu bulamadı:
        z-index olunca sliderlar her niyeyse çalışmadı. Saçmalığın zirvesi. */
        /*z-index: -10000;*/
    }

    .hero{
        max-height: 60vh;
        max-width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .hero img{
        height: 60vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: none;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .hero .he-active{
        display: block !important;
    }

    .new-hero-prev-slide{
        padding: 1em;
        border-radius: 100%;
        /*translate: 60px;*/
        left: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        /*background-color: white;*/
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .new-hero-prev-slide i{
        color: #59aee9;
        font-size: 80px;
        cursor: pointer;
    } 

    .new-hero-next-slide{
        padding: 1em;
        border-radius: 100%;
        /*translate: -60px;*/
        right: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        /*background-color: white;*/
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .new-hero-next-slide i{
        color: #59aee9;
        font-size: 80px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
        .hero img{
            height: 400px;
        }

        .new-hero-prev-slide{
            padding: 0.7em;
        }

        .new-hero-prev-slide i{
            font-size: 35px;
        }

        .new-hero-next-slide{
            padding: 0.7em;
        }

        .new-hero-next-slide i{
            font-size: 35px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
        .hero-container{
            margin-top: 10vh;
        }

        .new-hero-prev-slide{
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

        .new-hero-prev-slide i{
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .new-hero-next-slide{
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

        .new-hero-next-slide i{
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    }
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".new-hero-next-slide").on("pointerdown", function(){
            let currentImage = $(".he-active");
            let nextOfTheLatestCurrentImage = $(".he-active").next();
            let firstPicture = $(".he-first");
            let lastPicture = $(".he-last");

            if(nextOfTheLatestCurrentImage.length){
                nextOfTheLatestCurrentImage.addClass("he-active");
                nextOfTheLatestCurrentImage.prev().removeClass("he-active");

                if(lastPicture.hasClass("he-active")){
                    /*lastPicture.removeClass("active");*/
                    $(".hero img").removeClass("he-active");
                    firstPicture.addClass("he-active");
                }
            }
        });

        $(".new-hero-prev-slide").on("pointerdown", function(){
            let currentImage = $(".he-active");
            let firstPicture = $(".he-first");
            let lastPicture = $(".he-last");
            let prevOfTheLatestCurrentImage = $(".he-active").prev();

            if(firstPicture.hasClass("he-active")){
                firstPicture.addClass("he-active")
            } else if(prevOfTheLatestCurrentImage.length){
                prevOfTheLatestCurrentImage.addClass("he-active");
                currentImage.removeClass("he-active");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

so how can i put mobile menu on front of the slider and pictures and won't break the slider?